# Postfix - distribution of mail users not working

Tags: postfix, users, virtualization, mailbox

I have problem with distribution emails, I need email from domain **@cokdeje.cz** send to user forexample **info**, from domain **@surfujeme.cz** to another, etc.

**/etc/postfix/main.cf**

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
myhostname = mail.surfujeme.cz
virtual_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
mydestination = $myhostname, /etc/postfix/domains
relayhost =
mynetworks =
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter =
inet_interfaces = all
myorigin = /etc/mailname
default_transport = smtp
relay_transport = smtp
inet_protocols = all
home_mailbox = Maildir/
```

My virtual users (it's probable not work):

**/etc/postfix/virtual**

```
webcreating.cz  DOMAIN
@webcreating.cz         info

surfujeme.cz    DOMAIN
@surfujeme.cz           info

frosty22.cz     DOMAIN
@frosty22.cz            info

e-lekce.cz      DOMAIN
@e-lekce.cz             info

cokdeje.cz      DOMAIN
@cokdeje.cz             info

zujimode.cz     DOMAIN
@zujimode.cz            zujimodecz
```

And my virtual users,

**/etc/passwd**

```
info:x:1001:1004:Vít Ledvinka,,,:/home/info:/sbin/nologin
zujimodecz:x:1002:1005::/home/zujimodecz:/sbin/nologin
...
```

And **/etc/postfix/domains**

```
zujimode.cz
surfujeme.cz
cokdeje.cz
frosty22.cz
e-lekce.cz
```

I add user to file virtual, run **postmap /etc/postfix/virtual** but still all messages are in **info** mailbox, but when I delete some row from virtual file (example I remove: **@zujimode.cz zujimodecz** email cannot send to this domain, but when I write anything like username (info/zujimodecz/elekce/..) still all emails are in info mailbox.

Thanks so much for help! I work with it for one week, but I can't solve it ;(

Answer (score 0):

Did define the domains in the virtual-file?

it needs to look like this:

```
example.com  ANYTHING
foo@example.com some-user
bar@example.com some-other-user
@example.com catch-all-user
```

Comment: I edit my post, to my actual changes which I maked by http://www.debian-administration.org/articles/243 but still not work, and all domain look like @surfujeme.cz (so when I change in **virtual* file **@surfujeme.cz  someone** all emails from all domains are sended to user "someone" irrespective of domain name.

Answer (score 0):

You should have virtual domains in the `virtual_alias_domains` and `virtual_maps_domains` configuration settings, not in `mydestination` as you currently do.

Comment: I repaired virtual-file like is above, and I tried virtual_alias_domain, virtual_maps_domains, but I still same problem, but I found mainly problem - all emails are sended to @surfujem.cz domain mailbox - it does not distinguish domain name. When I change in virtual file **@surfujeme.cz zujimodecz** all emails send to this mailbox.

Comment: Now, I found detailed information - it's ignore multiple domains and all emails are directed to domain from: **myorigin = /etc/mailname**, but when I change it to $mydomain, it still same

Answer (score 0):

I make some corrects, and now all emails are stored by $mydomain:

**main.cf**

```
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
biff = no
append_dot_mydomain = no
readme_directory = no
smtpd_tls_cert_file=/etc/ssl/certs/ssl-cert-snakeoil.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file=/etc/ssl/private/ssl-cert-snakeoil.key
smtpd_use_tls=yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
mydomain = surfujeme.cz
myhostname = mail.surfujeme.cz
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases
virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
virtual_alias_domains = /etc/postfix/domains
mydestination = $myhostname localhost /etc/postfix/domains
relayhost = 
relay_domains = $mydestination
mailbox_size_limit = 0
recipient_delimiter = 
inet_interfaces = all
myorigin = $mydomain
default_transport = smtp
relay_transport = smtp
inet_protocols = all
home_mailbox = Maildir/
```

**virtual**

```
webcreating.cz  DOMAIN
@webcreating.cz     info

surfujeme.cz    DOMAIN
@surfujeme.cz       info

frosty22.cz DOMAIN
@frosty22.cz        info

e-lekce.cz  DOMAIN
@e-lekce.cz     elekcecz

cokdeje.cz  DOMAIN
@cokdeje.cz     cokdejecz

zujimode.cz DOMAIN
@zujimode.cz        zujimodecz
```

---

When send email to some domain:

```
anything@surfujeme.cz
anything@zujimode.cz
anything@cokdeje.cz
```

Postfix ignore domainname and use domain from **main.cf** => setting **myorigin** which is from **mydomain** and in **virtual** file find correct user **info**.

How I repair it? I don't need ignore domain name ;( 
I try it for 1 week, still nothing.